# Can I avoid this code duplication in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I do need to display a content which position to fixed in the bottom of every pages on my site, like this.

```
<div class="footer-fix">
    <p>This is its contents......</p>
</div>

.footer-fix {
    background:#fff;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
}
```

My question is if I have a lot of pages in my site. So do I need to add this code in almost every webpages or is there any other way to do it without adding this code in every pages?

Hope somebody may help me out.

Thank you.

Comment: jquery wont help that's for sure

Comment: @JaromandaX: Of course it could, by generating those elements dynamically and inserting them into the document, on every page that the script gets embedded into. Whether that is a good way to do this, regarding accessibility or search engines, would be a different issue.

Comment: @CBroe, can you give me an example showing how to do it? Thank you

Comment: Well this is were single page application/website comes into picture. In short you can just load the contents on a page as a external view as and when required asynchronously using jquery.ajax.

Comment: Use angular... Problem solved

Comment: You are better off looking for a templating solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qz94zkmm/

first all, yes you can do it in jQuery. But not recommended!

Here's a function it can dynamically insert html & css styles into an element:

```
function appendHtmlTo(where, htmlText, cssText) {
  $(where).append(htmlText).append('<style text="text/css">'+cssText+'</style>');
}
```

and call this function:

```
appendHtmlTo('body', html, css);
```

which variables `html` and `css` define like this (there is a backslash at the end of each line):

```
var html = '\
<div class="footer-fix">\
    <p>This is its contents......</p>\
</div>\
';

var css = '\
.footer-fix {\
    background:pink;\
    position: fixed;\
    bottom: 0;\
    z-index: 999;\
    width: 100%;\
}\
';
```

be sure call this function when document ready!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you kindly tell me what is the reason to not recommend this solution. Thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

You can do it very easy with PHP just create footer.php file and insert code above in.
Then just call include("/path/to/footer.php"); in bottom of every page and that its.

Comment: Yes I can do it in php. But I was looking for a solution in jquery

Comment: @user3733831 Oh sorry my bad, then i must agree with CBroe u can do that but that in not good solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can use html  tag
Ex:

```
<body>
<header class="col-lg-12" style="background-color:#444444; ">
    //Here i have Header
</header>

<div class="container-fluid" style="padding:10px; height:600px;">
         // Here goes my Body 
</div>

<footer class="col-lg-12 text-center" style="background-color:#444444; height:50px;">
    //Here Goes my Footer
</footer>
```